# How to know type of NSManagedObject in NSManagedContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch data from `Core Data` and to show them in `UITableView`. My `NSFetchedResultsController` looks like this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PlanPreparation"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:_context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"plan_id == %@", _planCycleID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    // but if there is no results I am making another fetch by another type of NSManagedObject    
    if (_fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count == 0)
    {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest1 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity1 = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Preparation"
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:_context];
        [fetchRequest1 setEntity:entity1];
         NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ismer == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        [fetchRequest1 setPredicate:pred];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: sortDescriptor, nil];

        fetchRequest1.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;        

        //return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

If I am not retreiving something after first attempt to fetch, I need to set another fetch. In `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` I need to show data depends on type of `NSManagedObjectObject`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if ([[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] isKindOfClass:[PlanPreparation2 class]])
    {
        PlanPreparation2 *planDrug = (PlanPreparation2 *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CDPreparation *prep = (CDPreparation *)[[PTDataManager sharedManager]getDrugByID:planDrug.guid];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", prep.name];
    }
    else
    {
        CDPreparation *drug = (CDPreparation *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", drug.name];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

but logging shows that `-isKindOfClass:` don't work here, I am not getting into quotes at all.

*Question:*

How can I find out type of `NSManagedObjectObject`?

Comment: Have you tried with `isMemeberOfClass`

Comment: Thanks, @Leonardo! But it is also not helped

Comment: Then this should work (myManagedObject entity).name isEqualToString@yourObjectName please forgive my keyboard, it has suddenly change the key set. I hope you get the point.

Comment: Here is the correct statement, where your object name is the name in Core Data store: `[[myManagedObject entity].name isEqualToString:@"yourObjectName"]`

Comment: Tried to use `if([[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] entity].name isEqualToString:@"PlanPreparation2"])` but I am also not getting inside if statement

Comment: Have you tried to put a break point and inspect the object ? And see if it is what you expect ?

Comment: Oh, I found that for some reason my `-fetchedResultsController` returns zero objects. I'll fix it,try your solutions, and here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

as shown in the picture change the name and class in data model inspector of that entity

name and class field in data model inspector must be same as name of entity table.

and then after you can compare like

```
if([(NSManagedObject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] isKindOfClass:[Category class]])
```

as "category" is the class in my case you can choose your own as you write above  [PlanPreparation2 class]

if still you face problem then comment below